Anime in which the main character is summoned to another world by a god or goddess who puts a curse on his skills that makes him barely able to get XP
The anime, as I remember, starts with the main character getting summoned to another world and a god or goddess that summoned him puts a curse on his skills that makes him barely be able to get XP, so he levels up slowly.
I've only seen 1 episode a while ago and this is all I can remember.

In roughly which year did you watch this?

I had to check, but Hell Mode: The Hardcore Gamer Dominates in Another World with Garbage Balancing doesn't have anime (nor 'curse' per se). It would kinda sorta fit.

You could improve this Anime Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

What's the upside of him levelling up slowly? Does this make him overpowered in some other fashion later on, or is he just cursed to spend the entire anime as a weakling?

Idk, it was new somewhere between 2019-2022 and i only watched 1 episode cuz that was all that was out at the time before i lost it

Are you sure this was an anime? The manga series Level 1 no Saikyou Kenja (AKA. Level 1 Strongest Sage) very closely resembles this description.

One day, Saijou Haruto was forcefully transmigrated and cursed by a god from another world. A world of swords and magic. In this world you get stronger by increasing your battle levels. But due to a curse, Haruto is unable to gain levels. However, due to a mistake by the Evil God, Haruto was able to obtain an inexhaustable supply of magic…




I think what i saw was a anime cuz i dont read manga an the goddess slowed his leveling, for example if 1 person requires 20 slime kills to lvl up then the mc needs bout 200 and he was summoned with a group of people
